# Symfony Controller - Adding Attributes

Tags: php, symfony

I have a custom controller that extends `controller` (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`) which in turn extends `ContainerAware` (`Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware`).
In all my functions I am using;

```
$foo = $this->get('foo');
```

So I want to be able to construct my class like so;

```
<?php
class FooController extends Controller
{
    private $fooManager;

    function indexAction()
    {
        // ...
        $this->fooManager->getAllFoo($scope);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Adding a constructor in my custom class won't work as the `ContainerAware` sets the container in `setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)` function.
I have tried overriding this function in my controller but still no good.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for this - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

You need to define your controller as a service and inject dependecys and classes to contructor. It will be hard if you're going to use container aware because you will need to call `setContainer` method (it can be done from service configuration).

regards,
Piotr